# How to use mercurial for release management?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, release-management

This is a cousin question with my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719019/how-to-manage-concurrent-development-with-mercurial) of "How to manage concurrent development with mercurial", which covers individual developer workflow. The answer to this question will actually influence the choice for developer workflow.

This is *NOT* a general "release management best practice" or CI question, as it has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134778/release-management-best-practice) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300703/what-release-management-solutions-are-worth-investigating) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714925/version-control-and-release-management) with good answers, and there's a huge body of literature available to kill time.

I'm only asking for **specific ways to use mercurial within the context of release management**.

The most obvious and predominant answer would supposedly be **stable/default**, which is thoroughly covered by the [beautiful blog](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/05/mercurial-workflows-stable-default/) of @Steve Losh, and more concisely in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405604/managing-release-branches-in-mercurial/1406906#1406906) from him. It's simple and effective.

A prominent example of this setup is hg itself. hg uses [a few more repositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/DeveloperRepos) for active development, but for release management purposes everything seems to be contained in the stable/default branches of the [main repo](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg).

The hg setup actually manifests a variation, or rather an extended version, of stable/default: **branch clone**. I described the process in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890723/mercurial-named-branches-vs-multiple-repositories/3757525#3757525) to a question on named branch vs. multiple repos (with another [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890723/mercurial-named-branches-vs-multiple-repositories/890892#890892) from @Martin Geisler). What I forgot to mention in my answer is how branch clone works for developer workflow: if you need to fix a bug for a branch, you would `hg clone <main repo>#<branch>` but *not* the branch clone, because your changeset will still go back to the main repo and pushed out to branch clone automatically. Of course you can choose not to clone and just `hg update <branch>` in your main clone, but most arguments for using separate clones (especially the independent build) apply here.

Now back to the question: **Are there any other ways that fit different real-world scenarios?** For example, a traditional major/minor/patch release cycle with long lapse between releases probably require quite a different workflow than a fast-paced, release-as-you-go web application. Please also comment on the stable/default and branch clone approaches if you feel like.

Since this is almost a survey question, I can only try to accept the "best" answer subjectively. If I can get a few more answers than my developer workflow question, that is.

Thank you for all your inputs!

Comment: Same as my workflow question, this is not at all limited to hg and I hope users of other DVCSs could also share your experiences and advices.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216212#216228

Comment: @VonC: +1 there and for the comment to support the sprint for #8!

Comment: What part about this are you confused about? You've given quite the eloquent layout on the question in the first place. What are you looking for feedback on?

Comment: @drachenstern: I was asking for comments on the stable/default scheme, and alternatives. Given no answer in 2 months, it seems like there's no alternative :)

Comment: The stable/default branch works fine for Mercurial itself. Projects that have to keep multiple "stable" branches active at the same time should probably go for something similar but use release-major numbers as the name of the named branch, e.g.: named branches "1.x", "2.x", "3.x", etc. Then specific releases may be tags that point to changesets of the "REL.x" branches, e.g. "1.1", "1.2" to point to the "1.x" branch.

Comment: @Giorgos Keramidas: thanks for the comment. That's exactly the scheme that I got my company into :)

Comment: @geofrrey, giorgos: I have to choose a workflow for my company ans I'm on something similar. one one you could post an answer, it is easier to find than a comment ... I will do when I can spare 5 minutes. cheers.

Comment: I think this probably is just a variation of stable/default, but I love the picture and how the information is presented here (more than just release management): http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ . Even though its based on git, I believe the concepts are portable to hg.

Answer (score 8):

I'm in the process of re-designing our workflow for release. So I've found this question. I've decided to wrote my experience. For what it's worth ...

---

For development, we are using something that seems to be variation of what you call the *stable/default* workflow (of course everything goes through commands that enforce the workflow, I call them `myw` thereafter) :

- we have a central server which holds all of our repositories
- we have a central *stable* clone per project on this server
- we have a central *dev* clone per project which is a clone of *stable* on this server
- initially, one can `myw create theproject` which create the *stable/dev* clones for theproject on the server and that locally (on the developer computer)
- when someone has to develop a new feature he can `myw clone theproject dev mygreatfeature` that :

  - clones the project *dev* repo on the server as *mygreatfeature*
  - clones locally the cloned repo *mygreatfeature*
  - makes lot of useful things like updating hgserver / hudson ci ...
- he can `myw fetch dev` and `myw fetch stable` anytime
- when the feature is done he merges it back to his local dev clone, push the merged result on the central *dev* clone and close the central clone which is archived for a while : `myw close theproject mygreatfeature`

All of that works great and is pretty smooth. We have preferred clones to named branches as it was simple to really close a feature branch, and at the time the mercurial "named branch" part seemed like "work in progress".

---

The release part of the workflow is presently done basically like that :

- the "release master" fetches from the central *dev* clone to his local *dev* clone.
- he fetches from the central *stable* clone to his local *stable* clone.
- he fetch from his local *stable* clone the changes that are in his local *dev* clone.
- he checks everything, if it is ok, do `myw release 1.2.3_RC2` that :

  - tag with 1.2.3_RC2
  - push to the centralized project stable clone.
  - this is in fact a *release candidate*, that will be tested for a while by our CI server and by our hardcore testers.
- Bug fixes discovered by those tests are fixed on the local *stable* clone and pushed on the centralized *stable* clone.
- when its ok, the "release master" do a formal release : `myw release 1.2.3`

That works pretty well, even if we needs to improve some commands to smooth the process. One of the main drawback it's that's a lot of clones :)

For the management of old releases, we have currently a clone of *stable* done for each major release. As there is no big need to backport many features, we just have to cherry-pick some really bad bugs with `hg transplant` (great extension by the way).

---

We have used that for about a year, and we certainly need to improve our homemade commands, especially for the release part :)

The main drawback is that you have to give you/your team some tools to handle it because without them it could be unmanageable, hence our `myw` homemade set of commands. As usual, the feature branch should not last for too long, or merging can be hard to do. Things like refactoring/renaming has to be done at chosen points, or it will give your team a lot of merging work.

As we are going to have more and more versions to maintain, I'm trying to improve the 'old release but have to support' management part. Reading *Bert F* comment, I've read this great [article](https://bitbucket.org/yinwm/hgflow/wiki/Home). There is good ideas and it is well explained with a really good scheme ! It seems someone has implemented the hg version of his tool git-flow as [hg-flow](https://bitbucket.org/yinwm/hgflow/wiki/Home). Something to consider. I like the release and hotfixes branches. And I think that enforcing such workflow with a tool is pretty well mandatory !

my2c